# Essential Supremum over a set of random variables attaining maximum

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I think the following result is true, but I cannot find any source online, so I post it here for confirmation:

Fix a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, an arbitrary index set $\Lambda \neq \phi$, and a family of real valued random variables $(Y_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. It is well known that if for each pair of $\lambda,\lambda'$, there exists $\lambda^*$ such that $Y_{\lambda^*}\geq \max\{Y_\lambda,Y_{\lambda'}\}$, then there exists a subsequence $\lambda_n$ such that $\lim_n Y_{\lambda_n} = \text{esssup}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}Y_\lambda$ a.s..

Is the following true? Suppose that $Y$ is continuous in $\lambda$ a.s., and $\Lambda$ is compact, then this essential supremum can actually be achieved. The proof would be simple, as $\Lambda$ is compact, the sequence $\lambda_n$ has a convergence subsequence, then the essential supremum will be reached by the limit of that subsequence, as Y is continuous. Is there anything that I overlook?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but can you not built counterexamples using BM? $(B_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ is  $\mathbb P$-almost surely continuous but I believe the ess-sup is infinity and definitly not taken, what do you think?

Comment: I am sorry that may be I did not state the question clearly, what I meant was in addition to the condition in the second paragraph, which is for every pair, there exists one to make the value larger. In your example, I dont think this is guaranteed.

Comment: Ah allright sorry I misread your question.